# Tfs Format Files C# project

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I am new to c# programming, i have completed a project in c# and my testers want to test it now.They want the code in tfs format. I am bit confused what should i give to them what is this Tfs format. I have got Aspx,Cs file of my project. My project is a 3 based on 3 Tyre architecture.

Please can anyone help me in this. That is this TFS format and how should i give them my source files in tfs format.

Comment: Have you asked your testers what they mean by _TFS_? The only thing that comes to mind for me when I see _TFS_ is [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).

Comment: TFS is a version control system. Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server

Comment: "Source code needs to be provided to us in TFS format"... this is what they told me

Comment: I dont know what should i give them now

Comment: **If you are a graduate/junior**.. no one is waiting that you should know how TFS works. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification or help. You only would fail if you don't know how to do something and you don't do anything to fix it

Comment: Its just me in the coding department, actually i am a Java Programmer its my first project in C# and i am outsourcing for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't know of I'm assuming they mean they want the code checked into Team Foundation Server source control.  This probably allows them to set up automated testing using the latest code for their tests.

TFS is a shared server solution that (presumably) your client/company already has installed.  It's not a "format" that you "export" your project to.  It is (among other things) a source code repository, meaning you upload your code to the repository to share with others.

With Visual Studio 2008 all you should need (if it isn't installed already) is Team Explorer.  That will let you add your code to source control, and will let "them" download it to do their tests.

There are a lot of variables with connecting to TFS (what version of Visual Studio?  What version of TFS?) but once you're connected you should be able to right-click the project and click "Add project to Source Control."

However I would strongly suggest you ask "them" what servers they use, where the code should be stored, etc. before doing something you have to undo later.

Comment: They want to check the code, i am using Visual Studio 2008. Can i give them the project files ?

Comment: No. "Check in the code" means upload it to TFS.

Comment: So you mean i download Team Foundation Service and connect it to my code and build tfs files from it ?

Comment: Probably you are using Visual Studio 2010 professional. That version contains a **TFS Explorer** embedded. I have updated my answer telling you how to upload it...

Comment: i will check it and will get back to you thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @user1457334 I have updated my answer to address your additional questions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a lot of things... I am pretty sure that your are programming something that is not integrated in your Source Repository software (standalone)... in your case TFS.

**What you have to do is add your solution to TFS (maybe ask for help to any senior there) in order to allow it to be either built or downloaded by testers.**

In order to "check in the code":

- Go in Visual Studio to File\SourceControl
- Click "Add Solution to SourceControl"
- Choose where to upload it

**NOTE**: What you should really do is tell them something like: "Hey, I have finished your project. I don't have experience with TFS nor I know in which directory should I upload it... Could someone help me to upload the code?"